# Getting Errors on paypal Website Payments Standard ( Java API)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to the paypal api system, I am integrating payment gateway on 
my web application using java/servlet api, i have gone through this link
**https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks**
in that i have downloaded **"Website Payments Standard"** java.zip file from there i am executing the 
sample i am getting the error as "**Illegal key size"**, kindly help me out in solving this one, And 
how to get the private keypassword in sandbox environment, i have created sandbox account.